# Calling loop variable into autocomplate select

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, web

```js
for (a = 1; a <= 2; a++) {

  $("#inp-" + a + "  .nama").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "states_remote.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
          term: request.term
        },
        success: function(data) {
          response($.map(data, function(item) {
            return {
              value: item.nama,
              pangkat: item.pangkat,
              jabatan: item.jabatan,
              nip: item.nip
            };
          }));
        }
      });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      $("#inp-" + a + " .pangkat").val(ui.item.pangkat);
      $("#inp-" + a + " .nip").val(ui.item.nip);
      $("#inp-" + a + " .jabatan").val(ui.item.jabatan);

      $(this).next('.nama').focus();
    },
    html: true,
    open: function(event, ui) {
      $(".ui-autocomplete").css("z-index", 1000);
    }
  });
}
```

i want use loop variable `a` into autocomplate select function, but i cant get access to call variable in this function

```js
select: function(event, ui) {
  $("#inp-" + a + " .pangkat").val(ui.item.pangkat);
  $("#inp-" + a + " .nip").val(ui.item.nip);
  $("#inp-" + a + " .jabatan").val(ui.item.jabatan);

  $(this).next('.nama').focus();
},
```

can someone help me to solved my problem? i search in other topic maybe this name is asynchronous function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using a closure:-

```js
for (a = 1; a <= 2; a++) {

  (function(a) {

    $("#inp-" + a + "  .nama").autocomplete({
      source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "states_remote.php",
          dataType: "json",
          data: {
            term: request.term
          },
          success: function(data) {
            response($.map(data, function(item) {
              return {
                value: item.nama,
                pangkat: item.pangkat,
                jabatan: item.jabatan,
                nip: item.nip
              };
            }));
          }
        });
      },
      minLength: 2,
      select: function(event, ui) {
        $("#inp-" + a + " .pangkat").val(ui.item.pangkat);
        $("#inp-" + a + " .nip").val(ui.item.nip);
        $("#inp-" + a + " .jabatan").val(ui.item.jabatan);

        $(this).next('.nama').focus();
      },
      html: true,
      open: function(event, ui) {
        $(".ui-autocomplete").css("z-index", 1000);
      }
    });

  })(a);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way and i feel that would be a better one:

```js
$(".nama").autocomplete({ // <----all the ".nama" element will be initialized
  source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "states_remote.php",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        term: request.term
      },
      success: function(data) {
        response($.map(data, function(item) {
          return {
            value: item.nama,
            pangkat: item.pangkat,
            jabatan: item.jabatan,
            nip: item.nip
          };
        }));
      }
    });
  },
  minLength: 2,
  select: function(event, ui) {
    // event.target will be the ".nama" element and 
    // as per your code it seems that the elements are sibling 
    // elements of the ".nama", so use `.end()` to get back to 
    // $(event.target)
    $(event.target).siblings(".pangkat").val(ui.item.pangkat).end()
                   .siblings(".nip").val(ui.item.nip).end()
                   .siblings(".jabatan").val(ui.item.jabatan);

    $(event.target).focus();
  },
  html: true,
  open: function(event, ui) {
    $(".ui-autocomplete").css("z-index", 1000);
  }
});
```

Comment: where's the looping? i need declare diferent class to input the value